# How to define a PHP variable as a specific class type before instantiate an object?

Tags: php, types

I am creating my own `MVC` framework, and I want it to be very basic, but when I use some `IDE`'s like `Eclipse` or `NetBeans` they tend to give me warnings telling that those variables where not initialized or they do not recognize what type they are, so they do not `autocomplete` the class methods or properties the variable supposed to be of.

To override this, I created a PHP file where the the global environment variable is set and a new object is instantiated and then destroyed, so the IDE recognizes it and I can work with it well.

But then these classes constructors execute at that time, and it could be dangerous and even slow down my code. So, to override this better, how could I define a variable type to be of a specific class, without instantiate it?

Like in `Delphi` we do `var Test = TTest;` and in `Java` we do `String testString;` before `testString = new String;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PHP is loosely typed, so you can't do it like you do in Java. You can provide type hinting for custom classes, though. See this description on PHP.net: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: that is suitable, thanks. I can create a hinted parameter in the class method I am using the external object.

Answer (score 50):

Depending on the IDE, you can use PHPDoc comments to get code completion

```
 /** @var YourClass */
 private $variable;
```

This is IDE specific though

Edit and 6 years later (almost to the day), with the advent of php 7.4, you can now declare types for class properties:

```
Class SomeClass
{

    private YourClass $variable;

    public string $something_else;

}
```

Comment: Here is the official documentation of **PHPDocumentor**: https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html

Comment: This helps indeed, used it in eclipse. Thx!

Comment: do you happen to know if this works in NetBeans 8.2? and, if it does, should I provide the relative path to the class for it to work, or just `YourClass` should do it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know now that Facebook developers created a PHP variant called [Hack](http://hacklang.org/), which is a PHP with strong types.

Answer (score 0):

> Type declarations can be added to function arguments, return values, and, as of PHP 7.4.0, class properties.

Off course not for all php versions!

[see more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php)